# Will Dispose be called first and cause a failure in case of deferred execution?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, deferred-execution

There are two methods, one of which returns a data using LINQ within a `using` statement. I wonder if it's possible for the query to throw some sort of an exception because the query execution is deferred and a variable it's using has already been disposed?

```
class Foo
{
    void Bar()
    {
       var bazResult = Baz();
       //... use bazResult here...
    }

    IEnumerable<int> Baz()
    {
        using (var d = new SomeDisposableSource())
        {
            return d.Select(e => e.Id);
        }
    }
```

}

BTW, it must have been asked already in some form but I can't find the obvious candidate. So don't kick me too hard :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you will have an exception if the object is disposed. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456691/how-does-linq-defer-execution-when-in-a-using-statement) is very similar and gives a couple of methods for handling the problem.  The simple one is to force execution by doing a `return d.Select(e => e.Id).ToList()` but that might not be suitable for you

Comment: I see, it makes sense. It also means that if I really want to avoid any overhead of execution (say, because I have IF statement in Bar that leads to no use of bazResult) then I'd rather avoid such constructs all together.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can throw an exception, but it depends on the implementation of "SomeDisposableSource". You are asking the source to get an IEnumerable or an Array before calling the Dispose(), but you are actually enumerating each element after the Dispose, so if  it throws and exception or not depends on the actual code for that "yeld-return" code. (does it use any disposed objects?)

You can work around it, (with higher memory usage) by doing:

```
return d.Select(e => e.Id).ToArray();
```

That way, all the enumeration is finished before you the Dispose() is executed.

EDIT: Using:

```
return d.Select(e => e.Id).ToList();
```

...may be better.

Comment: Also ToList() is better than ToArray(), as you avoid Array.Copy

Comment: @Magnus: Array.Copy() is what List.Add() uses when it needs to resize the underlying storage. So no, you don't avoid it.

Comment: @Pavel thats true, but ToArray() also does it. (check with reflector)

Answer (score 0):

`whether it's possible` is kind of strange question. Yes, it is possible. Your `SomeDisposableSource` may check whether it was disposed or not in `GetEnumerator` method.

Comment: Not so strange if you put it into real context. There may be much more code within using statement with the return in the end performing final filtering.

Answer (score 0):

I think Gerardo is on the right track but I would code it a bit differently which might result in a smaller memory footprint:

```
return d.Select(e => e.Id).ToList();
```

EDIT: Oops! IndigoDelta is way ahead of me

Comment: It's not ToList vs. ToArray it's WHERE they're called. d.ToArray/d.ToList might be much bigger becuase all of 'd' is written to the array/list vs. just the result of the select.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing up the (more) deterministic `using` statement with a (less deterministic) LINQ statement. By wrapping the resource `d` in that `using` statement you are explicitly stating that by the end of the method you would like it to be disposed.

Therefore if you would like to ensure `d` is disposed prior to the exit of the method, you'll have to make the LINQ execution immediate with `ToArray`, `ToList`, or some other method of that variety.

The <strike>much harder</strike>slightly more involved (*per commenter*) path would be to create a custom `IEnumerable<T>` which allowed the resource (`d`) to be returned with the LINQ statement and be executed at a later time, i.e. the caller is now responsible for disposing the `IEnumerable<T>` (usually simply through using a `foreach` block).

Comment: It's not really all that much harder - an iterator method (`yield return`) with a `using` inside it would do just that.

Comment: Hah, thank you sir. I've been wearing a DBA hat recently, forgetting about the simple solutions.

Answer (score 0):

In fact the execution is not deferred in your code because you use a regular `return`.
So the `Baz` method executes, returns and dispose. Later on, when you'll enumerate on the result, if this enumeration mechanism relies on unmanaged resources which have been disposed (which is most likely the case in your sample), this will fail.

The workaround is simple : don't prevent the deferred execution with a `return` but use a `yield return` instead. It's the accurate keyword to make deferred execution.

Your method becomes this

```
    IEnumerable<int> Baz()
    {
        using (var d = new SomeDisposableSource())
        {
            //return d.Select(e => e.Id); //Baaaad ! No proper deferred execution
            foreach (var i in d.Select(e => e.Id)) yield return i; //Proper deferred execution
        }
    }
```

and then all is ok. The `using` doesn't invoke the `Dispose` method before the enumeration is complete.

Comment: To complete this answer with a clearer explanation of what is at work, with `yield return`, an enumerated item is returned one by one till the end, and then `Dispose` is called. With `return`, an iterator is immediately returned and `Dispose`is called just after. But this iterator is not iterated on, and is not an instance of the type enumerated, but an instance of a "hidden" class which allow to enumerate the enumerated type. Thus we have (`return` = returning an enumerator of T instances with immediate execution) vs. (`yield return` = returning a T instance with deferred execution)